# SOLVED Having problems with paypal's REST API

Tags: javascript, json, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to create & send paypal invoices. I coded a function to create them using the paypal's nodejs sdk but it isn't working, i dont see the drafted invoices in the sandbox dashboard.

i'm making a discord bot that manages paypal invoices!

```
function createInvoice(item_name,item_description, quantity, cost, payer_email){ 

    let invoiceNumber = generateInvoiceNumber()

    fetch('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Prefer': 'return=representation'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "detail": {
              "invoice_number": generateInvoiceNumber(),
              "currency_code": "USD", 
            },
            "invoicer": {
               "email_address": config.emailAddress, 
            },
            "primary_recipients": [
              {
                "billing_info": {
                  "email_address": payer_email,
                }, 
              }
            ],
            "items": [
              {
                "name": item_name,
                "description": item_description,
                "quantity": quantity,
                "unit_amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": cost, 
                },
                "unit_of_measure": "QUANTITY"
              }, 
            ], 
          })
    }); 
    
    sendInvoice(invoiceNumber)
```

EDIT
i've checked the fetch result and it is returning me this error.

> {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token signature verification failed"}

this is the getAccessToken() function.

```
function getAccessToken(){
    var request = require('request');

    request.post({
        uri: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Language": "en_US",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        auth: {
        'user': config.clientId,
        'pass': config.clientSecret,
        // 'sendImmediately': false
      },
      form: {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
      }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        let { access_token } = JSON.parse(body)
        console.log(access_token)
        return access_token;
    });
  
}
```

I updated my getAccessToken function to this but it is still giving me the invalid_token error.

```
async function getAccessToken(){

    const response = await fetch('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', {
        method: "post",
        body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
        headers:{
            Authorization:
                "Basic " + Buffer.from(config.clientId + ":" + config.clientSecret).toString("base64")
        },
    });
    
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
        
}
```

Comment: "it isn't working" -- elaborate. What is the problem? Log the request and response.

Comment: it isnt showing the invoice in the dashboard, i said it in the message, there are no errors in the request.

Comment: Oh i've just checked, it's returning me this error: {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token signature verification failed"}, I'm going to paste here my getAccessToken() function.

Comment: did you try doing a test by calling the POST with curl or some different tool?

Comment: i will try and update you soon!

Answer (score 1):

Request.post is asynchronous. The getAccessToken function will not wait until you received the response, it will just finish the function and return undefined. Use async/await. Also be aware that currently the getAccessToken function itself has no return value. The return is within the callback function.

Comment: Check https://www.codecademy.com/learn/fscp-async-javascript-and-http-requests/modules/fecp-learn-javascript-requests/cheatsheet

Comment: i tried doing that, the response is correct, the token is correct, i dont know why it still gives me the invalid_token error

Comment: Try adding the content type header - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: still giving error...

Comment: How long ago did you request the token ? More than 3 hours ?

Comment: Issue might be the same as before with the request.post. So again the function fully executes without waiting to get the response from the getAccessToken function - try this: async function createInvoice(item_name,item_description, quantity, cost, payer_email){ 

let invoiceNumber = generateInvoiceNumber();

const accessToken = await getAccessToken();

fetch('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices', {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken} … rest of your code goes here